# Why is my function not giving correct output?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion

My function checks that whether an array is sorted or not using recursion. 
Unfortunately, it is returning `false` for every array.

```
Function call : sorted(a,0,a.length) where a[] = {1,2,3}; 

boolean sorted(int[] a , int s , int n)
{
    if(s+1==n)
        return true ;
    if(a[s]<=a[s+1])
        sorted(a,s+1,n);
    return false ;
}
```

Comment: Why use recursive approach when you can do it using iterations?

Comment: Do you mean to `return sorted(a, s+1, n)`? Currently you are discarding the return value from your recursive call.

Comment: I know. I am just learning recursion. It is a simple program but I am stuck with it.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks so much. It works. I was calling recursively if the  condition is true. It should return false where the condition is not satisfying. At the end, it should return true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are ignoring the result of the recursive call to `sorted`. Just return it, and you should be fine:

```
boolean sorted(int[] a , int s , int n)
{
    if(s+1==n)
        return true ;
    if(a[s]<=a[s+1])
        return sorted(a,s+1,n); // Here!      
    return false ;
}
```

Comment: What will be the difference between returning and non returning it. Can you please explain ? I am a little confused. Since in both cases, recursion is there,

Comment: @akisonlyforu without returning, you just don't do anything with the result. Even if the recursion terminates with `true`, you just return `false` from the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use result of recursive call. Perhaps it may look like

```
 if(a[s]<=a[s+1])
      return sorted(a,s+1,n)
 else
     return false;
```

or (if Java uses fast evaluation of complex conditions):

```
return (a[s]<=a[s+1]) && (sorted(a,s+1,n))
```

Comment: What will be the difference between returning and non returning it. Can you please explain ? I am a little confused. Since in both cases, recursion is there.

Comment: When you just call recursive function without assigning its result - you ignore its work at all. Call chain will end at the array end, but you don't know about check results. Imagine that you ask for some people in the bus to buy a ticket for you. The last man gets ticket and doesn't give it back...